# My equation is too wide on the screen

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I have a mathematical equation, its too wide .. I am unable to insert "\\" because it gave an error.
please help me to write this equation

```
\begin{align}
  \dfrac{{\pi}\left(s\left(4y^2\left(s\left(2y^2\left(s\left(4y^2
  \left(s\left(4y^2+1\right)+12\right)+s+11\right)+52\right)+s+11\right)
  +52\right)+s+11\right)+52\right)\mathrm{e}^{-4sy^2}}{2048s^5}
\end{align}
```

Comment: You mention, "I am unable to insert "\\" because it gave an error." It would be helpful if you mentioned which error you encounter. Were the errors by any chance related to your use of `\left` and `\right` sizing directives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `splitdfrac` macro of the `mathtools` package may be your friend.

[image]

None of the eight [8!] `\left` and `\right` directives in the numerator actually do anything useful -- the associated parentheses all have the exact same size! Worse still, they actually make it *impossible* to split the long numerator across two or more lines. Please get rid of the `\left` and `\right` directives *immediately*. If you want to throw your readers a visual bone, consider cycling between round parentheses, square brackets, and curly braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\splitfrac' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\splitdfrac{\pi\bigl\{s\bigl[4y^2\bigl(s\{2y^2
 [s(4y^2(s(4y^2+1)+12)+s+11)}{+52]+s+11\}+52\bigr)+s
 +11\bigr]+52\bigr\}\times\exp(-4sy^2)}}{2048s^5}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the denominator is quite small, I think that using `\splitdfrac` is a bit too sophisticated. The result is not highly legible, imho.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{multlined}
\frac{1}{ \text{ long } } \times \Bigl( \bigl( \text{a long mumbo jumbo of math } \\
\text{ mumbo jumbo of math continued } \bigr) \Bigr)
\end{multlined}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

and avoid `\left` and `\right` if you want to split.

[image]

Comment: @Mico Your comment is unclear to me; I explicitly said to avoid the \left and \right  construction. Am I missing something?